# Aframe systems[name] is not a constructor

Tags: aframe

I have an aframe project that has been part of a React app and working fine.

Because of various issues I'm trying to seperate the layers

I've added the aframe scene directly into the HTML document

```
  <body>
      <div id="root" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">

      </div>

      <a-scene>
      </a-scene> 

  </body>
```

The React part is rendering fine, but AFRAME is crashing with

> TypeError: systems[name] is not a constructor

from

```
 this.systems[name] = new systems[name](this);
 this.systemNames.push(name);
```

The aframe library is imported via Webpack.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue when using Aframe trough npm or when adding it with a script tagg when it has a `type="module"` or `defer` attribute.

### Working script:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

This is probably because you are using custom html taggs with a-frame. So the script should be loaded before it is parsing the html.

### Not working (currently on my environment):

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js" defer></script>
```

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js" type="module"></script>
```

```
>> npm i aframe
import aframe from "aframe";
```

Would be nice to see some comment/solutions on the not working variants.

**Setup**:
system: windows 10
bundler: vite
node: v16.13.0
aframe: v1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I was using Cloudflare with Rocket Loader. That’s why it wasn’t working. Once I disabled it, it worked fine.